# Unity: Keyboard Shortcut to Deselect Game Object

Tags: unity, interface

How do you unselect a game Object in the 3d view using your keyboard?

Comment: I don't know a keyboard shortcut. But if you click the Hierarchy, on an empty space, everything is deselected.

Comment: maybe this could help? https://answers.unity.com/questions/639981/quicky-deselect-all-selected-object-in-editor.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through the [list of Unity editor keyboard shortcuts](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityHotkeys.html), it doesn't look like such a shortcut exists.

We can save & load selection presets using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+(<kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>)+(<kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd>), but you can't directly save "no selection" into any of these slots. A workaround mentioned in the [link Arthur Gibraltar provided](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/162429/unity-keyboard-shortcut-to-deselect-game-object/162431#comment287395_162429) is to [create a dummy object, save a selection, then delete the dummy object to end up with a saved empty selection](https://answers.unity.com/questions/639981/quicky-deselect-all-selected-object-in-editor.html).

Instead of this fiddly process, we can add our own Select None shortcut with an editor script placed inside a folder called "Editor":

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;

public static class SelectionHelpers {

    [MenuItem("Selection/Select All (Active Scene) %a")]
    public static void SelectAll() {
        var scene = EditorSceneManager.GetActiveScene();
        var objects = scene.GetRootGameObjects();
        Selection.objects = objects;
    }

    [MenuItem("Selection/Select None %q")]
    public static void SelectNone() {
        Selection.objects = new Object[0];
    }
}
```

With this script we can Select All with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on Mac), 
 and Select None with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>)

Answer (score 2):

Extending from DMGreggory's solution, we could simplify the `SelectNone` function even more:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;

public static class SelectionHelpers
{

    [MenuItem("Selection/Select None %q")]
    public static void SelectNone()
    {
        Selection.objects = null;
    }
}
```

Where the selected objects is being reset to null as opposed to adding an empty object each time we call `SelectNone()`. This reduces the chances of memory leakage on heap and therefore is a safer solution.